# React router dom links are not scrolling to the correct section of the page (not scrolling at all)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom

I'm having an issue where my navigation bar created with React-router-dom is not "scrolling/taking" me to the right place in the page, in fact, it is not taking me anywhere at all. This is a single page app

This is my App component where I set the Router and the paths of each component

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from 'react'
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import HeroSection from './Components/HeroSection'
import AboutMe from './Components/AboutMe';
import Projects from './Components/Projects';
import Modal from './Components/Modal';
import Form from './Components/Form'
import ScrollTop from './Components/ScrollTop';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar'

function App() {

    const [show, setShow] = useReducer((p) => !p, false);

    const [data, setData] = useState()

    const handleData = (newData) => setData(newData)

    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <NavBar/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/aboutme' component={AboutMe}/>
                    <Route path='/projects' component={Projects}/>
                    <Route path='/contact' component={Form}/>
                </Switch>
           </Router>
            <HeroSection/>
            <AboutMe/>
            <Projects setData={handleData} setShow = {setShow}/>
            <Modal data={data} show={show} setShow={setShow} />
            <Form/>
            <ScrollTop></ScrollTop>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
            
}

export default App;
```

This is my `NavBar`where I set up the `Links`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa'
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai'
import {NavBarData} from './NavBarData'

const NavBar = () => {

    const [sideBar, setSideBar] = useState(false)

    const showSidebar = () => {
        setSideBar(!sideBar)
    }

    return(
        <>
            <div className="navbar">
                <Link to="#" className="menuBars">
                    <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar}/>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <nav className={sideBar ? "navMenuActive" : "navmenu"}>
                <ul className="navMenuItems">
                    <li className="navbarToggle">
                        <Link to="#" className="menuBars">
                            <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose/>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    {NavBarData.map((item, index) => {
                        return(
                            <li key={index}>
                                <Link to={item.path}>
                                    <span>{item.title}</span>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

I have a separate file `NavBarData` where I store the data for each link

```
export const NavBarData = [
    {
        title: "About Me",
        path: "/aboutme"
    },
    {
        title: "Projects",
        path: "/projects"
    },
    {
        title: "Contact",
        path: "/contact"
    },
]
```

I have created a miniversion in codesandbox which kind of works frustrating enough but I still can't understand what I am doing wrong.
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-currying-3o9oq?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

Apparently, you are trying to scroll to a specific section using `react-router-dom`.

#### Possible solutions

You can just use `a` HTML tag for that, using its `href` property with the section `id`.

#### Code

`sectionOne.js`

```js
function SectionOne() {
  return (
    <section id="sectionOne">
      children
    </section>
  )
}

export default SectionOne;
```

`NavBarData.js`

```js
export const NavBarData = [
  {
      title: "About Me",
      path: "#sectionOne"
  }
]
```

`NavBar.js`

```js
function NavBar() {
  return (
    {NavBarData.map((item, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        <a href={item.path}>
          <span>{item.title}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    )}
  )

export default NavBar;
```

#### Extra tip

1. Using a dependency for this will just increase your bundle size, so unless it really has more than one specific route, it's not necessary to install.
2. Using the CSS property `scroll-behavior: smooth`, you can make the effect when the scrolling starts.

Comment: Yea I know that. Forgot to mention that I am using react router simply to learn. Not really worried about the bundle size. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I see. Happy to help you. **Hint:** To close your question, click the check button

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out why it wasn't working. Apparently in single page apps where you need to be scrolled to a certain point in the page rather than navigating, you are meant to use `HashLink`

I ran `npm install --save react-router-hash-link` and used a HashRouter in my `App.js`, going to leave the code here in case someday someone faces a similar issue.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from 'react'
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import HeroSection from './Components/HeroSection'
import AboutMe from './Components/AboutMe';
import Projects from './Components/Projects';
import Modal from './Components/Modal';
import Form from './Components/Form'
import ScrollTop from './Components/ScrollTop';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar'

function App() {

    const [show, setShow] = useReducer((p) => !p, false);

    const [data, setData] = useState()

    const handleData = (newData) => setData(newData)

    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <NavBar/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/aboutme' component={AboutMe}/>
                    <Route path='/projects' component={Projects}/>
                    <Route path='/contact' component={Form}/>
                </Switch>
           </Router>
            <HeroSection/>
            <AboutMe/>
            <Projects setData={handleData} setShow = {setShow}/>
            <Modal data={data} show={show} setShow={setShow} />
            <Form/>
            <ScrollTop></ScrollTop>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
            
}

export default App;
```

**NavBar.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {HashLink} from 'react-router-hash-link'
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai'
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa'
import {NavBarData} from './NavBarData'

const NavBar = () => {

    const [sideBar, setSideBar] = useState(false)

    const showSidebar = () => {
        setSideBar(!sideBar)
    }

    return(
        <>
            <div className="navbar">
                <HashLink to="#" className="menuBars">
                    <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar}/>
                </HashLink>
            </div>
            <nav className={sideBar ? "navMenuActive" : "navmenu"}>
                <ul className="navMenuItems">
                    <li className="navbarToggle">
                        <HashLink to="#" className="menuBars">
                            <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose/>
                        </HashLink>
                    </li>
                    {NavBarData.map((item, index) => {
                        return(
                            <li key={index}>
                                <HashLink to={item.path} smooth>
                                    <span>{item.title}</span>
                                </HashLink>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

**EDIT:**

For this to work you need to give the section/element you want to scroll to an `id` attribute and the `HashLink` to parameter will take `/#idgiventoelement`